# Cart Promo Rule

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, promotions, special-price, rules

How can i set up a cart promo rule :

> ```
> If a customer buy 3 items from products without special price, 
> then he/she get a discount 15% only for items in cart which haven't special price?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the solution.

**Conditions:**

1. Check when there is more than three quantity in the cart
2. For each row item that has more than three quantity and no special price.

[image: Price rule conditions]

**Actions:**

1. Fill in discount amount 15
2. Condition for this price rule; special price is not greater than zero

[image: Price rule actions]